# How can I package all nuspec files in all subdirectories from a given directory?

Tags: nuget

In ADO pipelines, it's possible to pass "***.nuspec" to the nuget task to package all nuspecs in a repository, regardless of where they are located within it. I'm trying to replicate that functionality for my development box so that I can package every nuspec inside my repo storage folder, but I can't seem to get the nuget pack command to take wildcards. I imagine I can probably work up a PowerShell script to find each package and run nuget pack on each one, but is there a better solution?

Tried passing "nuget pack ***.nuspec" on command line

Expected:
Recursively finds and packages all nuspec files inside current directory and subdirectories

Actual:
Error "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."